# Image hosted on SharePoint Online site does not load in e-mail

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, image

I am writing an e-mail to inform users of an upcoming event in our company. The e-mail contains a number of images for display, but also to track the opening rate of the e-mails.

To keep the size of the e-mail down I don't want to include the images in the email, but to load them from our SharePoint Online Site Assets. Everybody in the company has got access to the respective SharePoint Online site.

I use a simple HTML to include the images:

```
<img src="https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/SiteAssets/image.png">
```

The problem is that like this the images do **not** load in the e-mail. Instead of the image there is an error icon.

[image]

The images **do** load in the e-mail, when I host them on a public web server instead of SPO.

```
<img src="https://www.myprivatesite.com/image.png">
```

Why can I not load the images from SharePoint Online?

Comment: Check if this helps. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/image-rendering-issue-in-outlook-through-microsoft-flows-office-365/

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Unfortunately, none of the actions in the article helped. Images are already automatically loaded in the Outlook application and attaching the image is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: can you provide what is output in Email?

Comment: There is a simple error icon instead of the image. Edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Do you have on-prem single-sign-on setup with Office 365 so that users on your domain are auto-logged in to SharePoint Online, or, are they normally prompted for their credentials when logging on to SharePoint?

Comment: @willman we've got single-sign-on set up for O365.